# How sort a list of tuples by the first element in the tuple?

Tags: jinja2

I have a list of tuples that contains an integer and a datetime object. I would like to sort it by the integers. For example:

`list = (45, datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 25, 13, 20, 8, 332000)), (43, datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 25, 13, 17, 47, 873000)),...`

My code at the moment, which is incorrect is:

```
var sort = {{list|sort(reverse = True)}}
```

I saw that there is an attribute option in jinja, but was not able to use it to only sort by the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly hacky, but very flexible approach is to pass a function to do the sorting, like so:

```
context={
            'my_list':[(1, 'bar1'), (8, 'bar2'),(5, 'bar15'), (8, 'bar12'),(3, 'bar8'), (17, 'bar99')],
            'tup_sort':lambda tuples: sorted(tuples,key=lambda x: x[0])
            }
render_response('templates.html', **context)
```

Then in your template.html, you can use:

```
var sort = {{ tup_sort(my_list) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was pleased to find out that you can easily do this without a custom filter (see [source code](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py#L55)). You can specify multiple attributes using "." and use numeric indexes to process array/tuple indexes.

```
{% for assignment, submission in group|sort(attribute='0.name') %}
    {{ assignment.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've tried this advice and looks like it doesn't work for tuples/lists :( I use jinja 2.6

Comment: Perhaps it no longer works? That's disappointing, it was a nifty feature. My source code link is dead too - I should referenced a specific commit!